# Android Studio won't recognize device. Can't run apps

Tags: java, android, adb, driver

I'm having a problem with my adb interface driver,
 device manager says its up to date but I have the caution icon showing.
My laptop is reading the device but android studio wont read the device.

I'm using an Elephone P9000 and my laptop is running windows 10.

any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried restarting adb?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 (or 8, 8.1) you are unable to install unsigned drivers because the system enables driver signature enforcement by default. Try [this](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! task manager > processes > adb.exe > end process. android studio must be closed before doing this and reboot your phone too. worked for me, hope this helps someone!